# Automatically updating svn:external

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I'm splitting an SVN repository into two: **project1**, and **common**.  This way, I can also make **project2** which also depends on **common**.

**project1** will contain an `svn:external` link to **common**.  I'd like people to constantly develop against the `HEAD` of **common**, but literally pegging an `svn:external` to `HEAD` causes problems (e.g. tags will reference the current `HEAD` instead of the `HEAD` at the time of tagging).  Manually pegging a static revision is annoying because if we don't update **project1** for a while, then it's manager's will be more reluctant to take all of the changes from **common** as untested changes become a risk.  That leads to forking which we want to avoid.

How can one work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this script as a cron-job or systemd.timer from a linux server (using an account with write access to the repository).

This solves the problem where reverting to an older revision of **project1** will also revert to the version of **common** used at that time by constantly updating the pegged svn revision.

As an added bonus, if someone updates **common**, all projects running this script will automatically commit an external property update which can trigger CI (using something like Jenkins).  That means a commit to **common** will immediately be tested on all dependent projects.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Updates all svn externals in a remote repository
# argument 1 is the server
# argument 2 is the path to the externals directory relative to the server root
#
# Note: all externals in the repository must be relative to the server root.
# See `svn help pset`
#
# Example:
# If you have externals in https://example.com/svn/project1/trunk, then:
#
# this-script https://example.com /svn/project1/trunk
#

server=$1
repo=$2

# Get the commited properties
svn checkout $server$repo wc --depth=empty
svn pget svn:externals wc > wc.externals

# Remove empty lines
sed -i '/^$/d' wc.externals

# for each external in existing properties:
while read line; do

  # tokenize
  IFS='@ ' tokens=( $line )

  # extract interesting stuff from the tokens
  extrepo=${tokens[0]}
  rev=${tokens[1]}
  dir=${tokens[2]}

  # Query the external repository for the last change
  latest=$(svn info $server$extrepo | sed -ne 's/^Last Changed Rev: //p')

  # Write a new set of externals based on latest info
  echo "$extrepo@$latest $dir" >> wc.newexternals 

done <wc.externals

# Get the differences between the new and old externals
details=$(diff -y --suppress-common-lines wc.externals wc.newexternals)

# If differences exist (and the diff was valid)
retval=$?
if [ $retval -eq 1 ]; then

  # Set the new properties
  svn pset svn:externals -F wc.newexternals wc

  # Generate the SVN log
  echo "Automatic externals update" > wc.log
  echo $details >> wc.log

  # Commit the changes
  svn ci -F wc.log wc
fi

# Cleanup
rm -rf wc wc.externals wc.newexternals wc.log
```

The limitation is that it only supports externals configured relative to the same server's root.